# References on the same slide on beamer

Tags: beamer

I would like to put references on the same slide which is being referenced. The best place in my opinion will be above the short name of presentation and date row. How can I achieve this?
Mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 Here is text \footfullcite{westfahl:space}.
 % this writes ref01 in footnote Here is text    
 \fullcite{westfahl:space}. 
 % this writes ref01 in place 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a MWE of the code you already have, please.

Comment: Which `theme` are you using? Using `Madrid`, the footfullcite is just above the title/date-footer